# bind csv file with django model while showing as output within html

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a django model and csv file separately. What I want to do is that user upload a csv file with a single colomn ('fp_Item').If colomn line exists in the django model as per below

```
(queryset_list.filter(
                            Q(fp_Item__contains=query)))
```

I want to retrieve the necessary fields from the database and show within html if does not exists it shouldn't retrieve anything and leave empty but still should have to print the csv file line.

```
def check_fp(request):
    if not request.user.is_active:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['csv_file2']:
            myfile = request.FILES['csv_file2']
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
            data = csv.reader(fs.open(filename, mode='r'))
            queryset_list = fp.objects.all()
            lines=[]
            for row in data:
                if row[0] != 'fp_Item':
                    line = row[0]
                    lines.append(line)
                    query= line
                    if query:
                        queryset_list.filter(
                            Q(fp_Item__contains=query))
                        queryset_list= fp.objects.all()
                    context = {'lines': lines,
                               'instances': queryset_list,
                               }
                    return render(request, 'check_fp.html', context)
            context = {'lines': lines,
                       'instances': queryset_list,
                       }
            return render(request, 'check_fp.html', context)
        return render(request, 'check_fp.html', {})
```

lines.append(line) is working and writing csv column to html file but I couldn't somehow bind the django model and the csv column together. Isn't "if query" method usable for this scenario ?

Here is my html file:  I want to match line at retrieve description and detail,timestamp and updated fields from the database. Am I looping false here ?

```
                        <tbody>
                {% for line in lines %}
                {% for instance in instances %}
                        <tr>
                            <td width="25%>
                                <a href="#">  {{ line }} </a>
                            </td></tr>
                            <td>
                                {{ instance.description }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ instance.detail }}
                            </td>
                            <td width="180">
                                {{ instance.timestamp }}
                            </td>
                            <td width="180">
                                {{ instance.updated }}
                            </td>
                            <td width="200">
                            </td>
                        </tr>{% endfor %} {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but if you have `queryset_list = fp.objects.all()` as the last line of that `if query:`, the previous line is pointless. `queryset_list` will always have all the `fp` objects. You are also returning from within the `for` loop, so only the first iteration will run, after skipping the header.

Comment: hmm good point, I need to remove "queryset_list= fp.objects.all()"   What I try to do actually print all within the csv file to html file and if what I printed is already in my database retrieve and print next to csv file retrieved value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this below part,

```
if query:
                        queryset_list.filter(
                            Q(fp_Item__contains=query))
                        queryset_list= fp.objects.all()
                    context = {'lines': lines,
                               'instances': queryset_list,
                               }
                    return render(request, 'check_fp.html', context)
```

you need to modify as per below

```
queryset_list = FP.objects.filter(FP_Item = query)
            context = {'lines': lines,
                       'instances': queryset_list,
                       }
```